# passing variable from ngFor to the component's method

Tags: angular

**What I want to achieve:**

Everytime the user selects some option on upper-select in the code below, I want to execute the component's method onSelectSampleType with the selected object as parameter which sets some public property of component to the passed parameter.

```html
<select (change)="onSelectSampleType(SampleType)">
  <option  *ngFor="let SampleType of sampleTypeList">{{ SampleType }}</option>
</select>

<select *ngIf="selectedSample"">
  <option *ngFor ="let subType of selectedSampleType.subType">{{ subType }}</option>
</select>
```

**Problem:**
the SampleType parameter in onSelectSampleType() method which is supposed to capture SampleType of ngFor directive is capturing nothing and passing undefined value. I think the scope of SampleType variable inside ngfor directive is just limited to  tag.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want to achieve?

Comment: Scope of `SampleType` is `<option></option>` tag. And you calling `onSelectSampleType` out of scope.

Comment: I think I understood that in a hard way. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```html
<select (change)="onSelectSampleType(sel.value)" #sel>
  <option *ngFor="let SampleType of sampleTypeList; let i = index" [value]="i">{{ SampleType }}</option>
</select>
```

you should get index of selected option i think

Comment: Can you please explain what #sel does?

Comment: Declares local variable that you can use anywhere in the template to refer this element.
Look at the https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html for `<video #movieplayer ...>` example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to access the `SampleType` variable outside of the scope of the `ngFor` directive. Since you're outside of the scope you can't access the variable, so your `(change)` callback doesn't receive the data you want.

If the only purpose of your callback is to set the `selectedSampleType` property on your component, you can just use `ngModel` to bind the control to `selectSampleType` directly:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedSampleType">
  <option  *ngFor="let SampleType of sampleTypeList">{{ SampleType }}</option>
</select>
```

If you require a more complex callback, you can use `$event.target.value` to get the value of the option which triggered the `(change)` event:

```
<select (change)="onSelectSampleType($event.target.value)">
  <option  *ngFor="let SampleType of sampleTypeList">{{ SampleType }}</option>
</select>
```

You can find more information about Angular 2 event binding here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#event-binding

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value as below:

```
<select (change)="onSelectSampleType(selectedItem.value)" #selectedItem>
    <option *ngFor="let SampleType of sampleTypeList;let i=SampleType" [value]="SampleType">{{ SampleType }}</option>
</select>
```

TypeScript:

```
public sampleTypeList = ["SampleType1", "SampleType2", "SampleType3"];

public onSelectSampleType(sampleType: string) {
    console.log(sampleType);
}
```